# error: cannot find symbol in Android gradle library module unit test

Tags: android, intellij-idea, junit, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a test project in IntelliJ (using the Android Studio plugin) and I'm trying to set up unit tests as described [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

When running a junit test the project can't seem to find my sources under src > main > java. The following test

```
package io.adaptiv.plzwrk.lib;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AdaptivTest extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testDoStuff() throws Exception {
        assertEquals(42, Adaptiv.doStuff());
    }
}
```

gives the error

```
error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals(42, Adaptiv.doStuff());
                         ^
  symbol:   variable Adaptiv
  location: class AdaptivTest
```

My 'test' class

```
package io.adaptiv.plzwrk.lib;

public class Adaptiv {

    public static int doStuff() {
        return 42;
    }

}
```

The layout of my project looks like this

[image: project layout]

With settings.gradle

```
include ':lib'
```

The project build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The build.gradle under the lib dir

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
}
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this? How? :)

Comment: I ended up using Android studio and their built in test framework, wanted to get it working with IntelliJ (which should be identical) but it was taking too much time.

Comment: Thanks! In the end I gave up on getting them to run in a separate /test directory and let Android Studio decide where to put the test files (using ctrl+shift+t in the class-to-be-tested).... it seems to work now *fingers crossed*.